# Get average of certain groups if CRITERIA IS

Tags: excel, max, average, criteria

I'm trying to check what the average percentage of a KPI is for multiple groups at the same time. It should only be the last three groups I have though. I have made a complete example file that can be used as I find it complicated to explain (with instructions) and if successful, the value in C13 should change to TRUE:

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjWVkb2UBexjhzWtnniTr8JJel2z

Can anyone help? I'm completely lost as to where to begin.

Comment: `AVERAGEIFS()`? What does your data look like, what have you tried so far? (Please note that it's recommended to post a table here, instead of linking to an off-site spreadsheet, as few people are likely to download a random file).

Comment: Looks like homework to me.  What have you tried?

Comment: Bruce, it's excel online, no file download and instant access to edit.

Comment: Scott: I've only gotten this far as to know how to specify the value of the last row in the Group table. I know how to get an average of multiple groups with AVERAGEIFS(KPItable[KPI];KPItable[Group];i9;KPItable[Tenure];J9) (if I set "1" in J9) and that I can + the same formula changed to for i10 and split it by 2, if I want the average of two dates in i9 and i10. What I don't know is how to make a dynamic list of the groups that match the criteria "last 90 days" and thus also get the number of groups there are within that criteria. Today the number of groups could be 3, tomorrow it could be 4.

Comment: To better illustrate my train of thought: If there are 3 groups that fit the criteria of "last 90 days from the last date in [Groups]", I want to get 3 dates from [Groups] in i9, i10 and i11, but also get something that looks like "=(Averageifs(..)+Averageifs(..)+Averageifs(..))/3". And 4 "averageifs" split by 4 if there are 4 dates returned. I don't know where to begin to achieve this /:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. I really complicated this. I could have just added another tenure column that checked if they had worked less than 90 days, if the date of the data I wanted to check was <90 days, then used that in a simple AVERAGEIFS formula. Solved.